# Is my Nautilus config wrong after upgrading to 18.04 1

Tags: nautilus

I'm used to check many files properties with contexual-menu (right-click) property on each file name opening as many dialogs where I catch requested info.

Fine (to me) with 16.04 but 18.04 opens a first window that is modal,  so I can't go farther.

Desktop suffers the same decay.

Thunar still works as I whish.

I hope my settings are bad: I love Nautilus!

Comment: I think that is the normal behaviour in gnome